# What kind of storm tracks produce snow in the eastern United States?

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting, storms, snow

What storm tracks are favorable for snow in the eastern United States? Articles like [this one on a winter storm in the Northeast in 2011](http://www.accuweather.com/en/weather-news/upcoming-major-winter-storm-in-1/44817) indicate that storm tracks are important in snowfall amounts. But other winter storm tracks seem to produce more maritime tropical weather.

I know the heaviest snow usually falls to the west of the storm track where the cold air is located, but why do some storm tracks not produce any snow at all?  What influences the storm tracks that causes them to be prolific sometimes and duds other times?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, your question could be boiled down to "How does weather work?", which is far too broad a question for our Q&A format. Please check out our [tour](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tour) for information on how best to use this site.

Comment: Could we reform this question to say something more along the lines of: what storm tracks are favorable for snow in the eastern United States?  Would that be considered acceptable?  I don't see this as "how does weather work", I see this as what fine details are important for this specific type of setup.  I don't have many answers for this question, but seems like something that is both answerable and interesting.

Comment: I apologise for my vague question. @JeopardyTempest example was more along the lines of what I am asking.